# Swift 4.2 // Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I wrote code (you can find it below), but it partly doesn't work. I want to create an app, where I can push the button `pushMicButton` and when the button is pressed just tell some words and SpeechKit or something like this will recognise it and add the word, system have recognised, to  a recognizedLabel.text. I created such code, but I have a failure in line 43.

Could you help me and fix my code?

Thank you!

Code sample:

```
import UIKit
import Speech

class VoiceController: UIViewController {

    private let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "se-SE"))

    @IBOutlet weak var recognizedLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func pushMicButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Voice recognition button")
        voiceRecognition()
    }

    @IBAction func AddToListButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Add something to list")
        getAddedData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    func voiceRecognition() {

        SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch SFSpeechRecognizer.authorizationStatus() {
                case .authorized:

                    let audioURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "wav")!
                    let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
                    let request = SFSpeechRecognitionRequest(url: audioURL)
                    recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
                        guard error == nil else { print("Error: \(error)"); return }
                        guard let result else {print ("No result!"); return}
                        self.recognizedLabel.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                    }
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        //ADD VOICE RECOGNITION HERE

    }

    func getAddedData() {
        let originalString = recognizedLabel.text
        let escapedString = originalString!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
        let dataLink = "http://yabahi.st/items/find?name="
        let lookingURL = dataLink + escapedString!

        guard let url = URL(string: lookingURL) else {return}
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let dataResponse = data,
                error == nil else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                    return }
            do{
                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                    dataResponse, options: [])
                print(jsonResponse)

                //SEND "jsonResponse.name" TO MAIN UITABLEVIEW

            } catch let parsingError {
                print("Error", parsingError)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

Comment: *"I have a failure in line 43"* – do we have to count the lines, or will you tell us where the error is exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url:)` instead of `SFSpeechRecognitionRequest(url:)`

and change `guard let result else { print ("No result!"); return }`
to `guard let`result`= result else { print ("No result!"); return }`

it should solve all your errors in this code.

Comment: When I ran it it has new error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Answer (score 0):

The `voiceRecognition()` method should be implemented as:

```
func voiceRecognition() {
    SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch SFSpeechRecognizer.authorizationStatus() {
            case .authorized:

                guard let audioURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "wav") else {
                    return
                }
                let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
                let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: audioURL)

                recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Error: \(error!)")
                        return
                    }

                    guard let result = result else { print ("No result!"); return }
                    self.recognizedLabel.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                }

                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    //ADD VOICE RECOGNITION HERE
}
```

Now here are the differences:

1- For safety, you should avoid the force unwrap `audioURL`, `guard` statement would be a good choice.

2- If you are aiming to create a speech recognition request, initialized with the specified URL, you should use `SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest` instead of `SFSpeechRecognitionRequest`.

3- It seems that there is a misuse for the `guard`s...

Comment: No errors, but no recognition. And what should I change in code, if I want to see it works?

Comment: @yabashist try to debug the code (just adding a breakpoint should be sufficient to catch it), where is the issue?

Comment: I added `print(result)`and there were nothing